# How can I tighten a large nut under the sink?

Tags: tools, faucet

I just installed my new peerless kitchen faucet. I used my hand to tight the hex nut because the space is pretty small.(I think that the size is 1 1/2)

It is temporary. I tried [Basin Wrench](http://www.lowes.com/pd_331887-943-03812.UPP5_1z0wcfj__?productId=3220011&pl=1) and [adjustable wrench](http://www.lowes.com/pd_464603-16878-55749___?productId=50029414&pl=1&Ntt=adjustable%20wrenches). Both of them are not working because the handles are long.

See the sample image, the space appears to be large in the [demo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4NObA0pCCqE) but actually not in the real world.

I even thought to use [wrench driver](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Armstrong-12-867-Crowsfoot-Wrench-1-1-2-1-2-drive-/371495910039?hash=item567ee1ba97:g:JoEAAOxyu0BReoyw), but I don't want to try different tools and return them if not applicable.

Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The basin wrench you linked to would be the right tool if the hex nut was 1" or less. For a larger nut like this, it was designed to be either hand tightened, or with a wrench like the channel lock or adjustable wrench you linked to. But to use the wrench, you would need to first remove the sink from the counter.

Some newer faucets have worked around this problem by using a hand tightened nut that has two screws on either side. Once you tightened the nut as far as you can by hand, you tighten the screws which press against a washer, firmly holding down the fixture. If you can't get a basin wrench on it, and don't want to remove your sink from the counter, then I'd recommend taking this fixture back and finding one that would be easier to install in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Channel Lock pliers always worked well for me in those spaces or you can try a slip nut wrench those work well also

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have both of them but them don't work well.

Answer (score 0):

A shower wrench goes to 1 7/16"

[image: shower wrenches]

it has a chance of working. The last faucet I installed came with its own wrench to tighten that nut. This particular one is a set from the big box store, it has five wrenches in all with a handle. You may be able to find the larger one at a plumbing specialty store.

It is hollow through the length, the supply lines will go through the wrench to get to the nut.

Comment: Just contact the customer service. `The mounting nut for your model has and outside diameter of 1 7/8"`